# How to rewrite or add a column start from 1 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a dataframe like this
and I want to re-rank `Startup Rank` starting from 1,2,3,4... to end.
Or can I add a column start from 1,2,3,4.... and remove the `Startup Rank` column?

[image]

Comment: Try `df['Startup Rank'] = range(1, len(ranking1)+1)`. It will remove existing column and replace it with values 1,2,3...

Comment: Perhaps `df['Startup Rank'] = len(df) + 1 - df['Startup Rank']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the relative ranking, you can subtract the min value - 1:

```
df['Startup Rank'] -= df['Startup Rank'].min()-1
```

Or for a new column:

```
df['new'] = df['Startup Rank'] - df['Startup Rank'].min() + 1
del df['Startup Rank']
```

If you want a brand new ranking top->down 1->n:

```
df['Startup Rank'] = range(1, len(df)+1)
```